# Windows batch script: Check for occurrence in files

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a windows batch script.
Starting from a given directory, I need to check whether there is at least one occurrence of a given text in every file with a given file name.

E.g.:
Starting with the directory C:\MyDir, I need to check this directory and all subdirectories for files with the name "MyFile.txt". Every file found must have at least one occurrence of the text "MyText".

What I have so far is this:

`FOR /R C:\MyDir %%f in (MyFile.txt*) do (
    FINDSTR /i /c:"MyText" %%~f
)`

Problems:

- This would also match for files with the name MyFile.txtXXX
- It does only print occurrences but does not "return" whether such an occurrency is found. This code is inside a batch script which must exit with an error, if there is one file without such an occurrence.

Comment: why `MyFile.txt*`? Can this be translated to "find all 'MyFile.txt' that does (not) contain 'MyText')" ?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal: "find all 'MyFile.txt' that do not contain 'MyText'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findstr /v` does not work like intended here, so you have to use a little trick: use `findstr` and use it's errorlevel to find "string not found":

```
for /r %%a in (myfile.txt) do findstr /i "MyText" %%a >nul && echo yes: %%a|| echo no:  %%a
```

- `for /r` is recursive (search in subdirectories too) (use `for` instead of `findstr /s` to process each file one after the other to be able to check errorlevel for each single file instead of the complete `findstr /s` list)
- `&&` works as "if previous command (`findstr`) was successful, then"
- `||` works as "if previous command (`findstr`) failed, then"

Answer (score 1):

Read `findstr /?`: Searches for strings in files.

```
FINDSTR [/B] [/E] [/L] [/R] [/S] [/I] [/X] [/V] [/N] [/M] [/O] [/P] [/F:file]
        [/C:string] [/G:file] [/D:dir list] [/A:color attributes] [/OFF[LINE]]
        strings [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]
  …
  /S         Searches for matching files in the current directory and all subdirectories.
  …
```

Next command should find and display all matches:

```
FINDSTR /S /i /c:"MyText" C:\MyDir\MyFile.txt
```

Next command should find all matches and display only (fully qualified) file names:

```
FINDSTR /M /S /i /c:"MyText" C:\MyDir\MyFile.txt
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.
However, with this statement I have no possibility to find files without the given occurrence.